# Find an explicit second-degree polynomial given a definition of an inner product on a polynomial vector space

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $\mathcal{P}_2$ denote the vector space of of all second-degree polynomials from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Define the inner product on $\mathcal{P}_2$ to be:

$$\left< p,q \right> = \int_{-1}^{1} p(x)q(x) dx $$

**How can I find a unique, explicit polynomial $q(x) \in \mathcal{P}_2$ such that for *every* $p \in \mathcal{P}_2$, we have**:

$$p(1) = \int_{-1}^{1} p(x)q(x) dx $$

I started by defining $p(x) = a + bx + cx^2$ and $q(x) = \alpha + \beta x + \delta x^2$. Then I calculated $p(1)$, which equals to $a+b+c$. From this we get:

$$ a+b+c = \int_{-1}^{1} (a + bx + cx^2)(\alpha + \beta x + \delta x^2) dx $$

However, after this, no matter what I try, I cannot get explicit values for $\alpha, \beta$, and $\delta$. I tried plugging it into WolframAlpha, but each value depends on another value and the values keep changing from one case to another. Moreover, we cannot simply *fix* values for the constants because the above statement must hold for every polynomial $p \in \mathcal{P}_2$.

Comment: Here's a hint: Since you know it must be the case that $\langle p , q\rangle=p(1)$ for  $\textbf{every } p$, how about (perhaps carefully) selecting a few different $p$?

Comment: Theo's hint is good. Your approach works, too; multiply out that integrand, do the integration, and you'll get an equation in which the coefficients of $a,b,c$ (which are linear in the unknowns $\alpha,\beta,\delta$) have to be zero: three linear equations in three unknowns.

Comment: Any thoughts about the several comments and answers that have been posted, Curiosity?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Answer (score 1):

For $p(x)=1$ we get $1=\int_{-1}^{1} q(x) dx$.

For $p(x)=x$ we get $1=\int_{-1}^{1} xq(x) dx$.

For $p(x)=x^2$ we get $1=\int_{-1}^{1} x^2q(x) dx$.

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to define $q$ on a basis. A suitable basis is $e_k(x)= x^k$ for $k=0,1,2$.

Let $q(x) = q_0+ q_1x+q_2 x^2$.

Since $e_k(1) = 1$ for all $k$ we require $\langle e_k, q \rangle = 1$ for all $k$.

This gives the equations $2q_0 + {2 \over 3} q_2 = 1, {2 \over 3} q_1 = 1, {2 \over 3} q_0 + {2 \over 5} q_2 = 1$.

Hence $q_0 = -{3 \over 4}, q_1 = {3 \over 2}$, $q_2 =  {15 \over 4 }$.